# My OSPF Multi Area Topology is not reliable

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, subnet, ospf

I made an ospf multi area topology, but it's inconsistent. At times, host from the A area could ping to hosts in other areas however, sometimes otherwise (failed to arrive). Whenever I tried to do a ping test, 50% of the packet was successfully delivered and the rest was failed (packet loss).

This is my topology
[image]

This is my .pkt file

[Packet Tracer file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GO6YwhwLOukwA6vF00FeqVw3p_K-zBFQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to edit the question to include the router configurations. Most people do not use Packet Tracer because it is so limited. Simply copy the configurations and paste them into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`), which will automatically create scroll boxes for each configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One big problem I see right off the bat is that you have duplicate networks in Area 2 and Area 4.

The networks `172.16.1.0/16` and `172.16.2.0/16` are really the same network: `172.16.0.0/16`.

The networks `172.30.1.0/16` and `172.30.2.0/16` are really the same network: `172.30.0.0/16`.

That will cause an anycast situation, where the routing protocol will have the same network advertised from two different places, but there will only be one entry in the routing table, which is the closest (by the routing protocol metrics), so different routers in Area 0 will have different paths.

---

You certainly need to fix the addressing, and that may solve all of your problems, but there may be others that we cannot see because you didn't include the router configurations, routing tables, etc.

It appears that you do not have a full grasp of IPv4 addressing, and I would suggest that you read and understand the answers to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).